# Python strip function works only on the left side of a string

Tags: python-3.x, strip

I have a file with text lines that I want to strip the first and last characters and then store the stripped lines in a list. The text is something like:

%5 sdgfjfhlsjf %5
%5 alkdregtrlkjdls %5
%5 dgglssj %5

In order to get rid of the leading and trailing characters (%5), I used the strip function in a few variants of code, but I didn't get the expected result. The leading characters are stripped, but the trailing ones are still in place:

sdgfjfhlsjf %5
alkdregtrlkjdls %5
dgglssj %5

This is code I try to implement at the moment:

```
    stripped = []        
    with open ('/path/testfile') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            strippedline = line.strip("%5")
            stripped.append(strippedline)
```

Can someone tell me what my mistake(s) is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip` removes characters from both ends. In your case, the main issue though is that you have `\n` at the end of each `line`, so your code should remove that as well:

```
stripped = []        
with open ('/path/testfile') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        strippedline = line.strip("\n%5")
        stripped.append(strippedline)
```